# jQuery autocomplete, adds "ui-state-active" to the A inside of LI, how can I add a hover/selected to the LI?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete which makes a UL with items like:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
   <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
     <img src="/thumb/x.jpg">
     <span class="text">Mr Armstrong</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

The problem here is when you hover or select an item, the ui-state-active style is being applied to A when I want to applied to LI... Anyone else run into this? How can I have a class added to the LI on hover/active?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give the `<a>` a `display: block` so that it would take up the entire `<li>`, then it wouldn't matter (visually) where the `:hover` pseudo-class was:

```
/* Make this as specific as needed. */
li.ui-menu-item a {
    display: block;
}
```

CSS Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wZgLa/